# Exponential and regular Diophantines?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

I am looking for a reference on connections between exponential and "regular" (polynomial) Diophantine equations. For example, I was wondering about the Catalan-Mihailescu problem and I thought of the following two problems which can perhaps be called inverses of each other:

1. Find all integers $x,y$ such that $x^2-y^3=1$.
2. Find all integers $x,y$ such that $3^x-2^y=1$.

Is there any connection known between such inverse Diophantines?

Another example is Fermat's problem of solving $x^3-y^2=2$ in integers.

1. Find all integers $x,y$ such that $x^3-y^2=2$.
2. Find all integers $x,y$ such that $3^x-5^y=2$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The assertion that exponential Diophantine equations are usually much easier than "corresponding" ordinary Diophantine equations seems doubtful to me. There is often good theory for ordinary Diophantine equations in two variables. That is not the case for two variable exponetial Diophantine equations.

Comment: See [Ramanujan-Nagell equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan-Nagell_equation).